# Chrome Extension: How to List The Contents of Local Directory

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, filesystems, google-chrome-os

### What I want to do:

I want to create a Chrome extension for test purposes. And that extension should be able to **access** the directories and files on the local **hard drive**.

### How I did It:

I requested permissions for `file:///*` in my `manifest.json` file. Then I made sure that the checkbox `Allow access to file URLs` was checked. Then I made a XHR for a file:

```
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();  
  xhr.open("GET", 'file://c:/dir/file.name', true);     
  xhr.onload = function(e) {  
      console.log('response: ', xhr.response);
  }  
  xhr.send();
```

... and a XHR for a whole directory:

```
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();  
  xhr.open("GET", 'file://c:/dir/', true);     
  xhr.onload = function(e) {  
      console.log('response: ', xhr.response);
  }  
  xhr.send();
```

... and for the *total* file system:

```
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();  
  xhr.open("GET", 'file:///', true);     
  xhr.onload = function(e) {  
      console.log('response: ', xhr.response);
  }  
  xhr.send();
```

### What happened:

- I was able to get the right response for my file request.
- When I requested a directory I received the source code of Chrome's
  default human-readable directory overview:

.

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <script>
```

*[...]*

```
  </script>
  <style>
```

*[...]*

```
  </style>
  <title id="title"></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="listingParsingErrorBox" i18n-values=".innerHTML:listingParsingErrorBoxText"></div>
  <span id="parentDirText" style="display:none" i18n-content="parentDirText"></span>
  <h1 id="header" i18n-content="header"></h1>
  <table id="table">
    <tr class="header">
      <td i18n-content="headerName"></td>
      <td class="detailsColumn" i18n-content="headerSize"></td>
      <td class="detailsColumn" i18n-content="headerDateModified"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
```

*[...]*

```
  <script>start("C:\\dir\\");</script>
  <script>addRow("..","..",1,"0 B","11/11/11 11:11:11 AM");</script>
  <script>addRow("file.name","file.name",0,"4.9 kB","11/11/11 11:11:11 PM");</script>
```

- And when I requested the whole filesystem, I got an error.

### My Question:

I'm able to read simple files. But how can my extension get a nice **machine-readable overview of a directory** or of the total filesystem? Thanks.

***EDIT:*** I know that the FileSystem API is intended to access the sandboxed `filesystem://`, but maybe Chrome allows extensions to also access `file://`. I couldn't find any documentation concerning `file://` access from Chrome extensions, so I'm just able to guess.

Answer (score 3):

There's no built-in feature in stand-alone Chrome.

Alternatives to parsing the directory listing page:

1. NPAPI extensions (C++, recommended)
2. a local server with filesystem access. [NodeJS is a good pick](http://www.ipreferjim.com/2011/12/install-nodejs-under-chromeos-cr-48/).

Comment: Thanks, but Npapi (or any external software) is not an option for me. If nobody has any idea concerning that, I need to write a parser for chrome's human-readable directory overview. But that's not what I wanna do because the structure of the directory overview's source code can change in later chrome releases.

Comment: Chrome never exposed any directory reading capabilities because under normal conditions, the Filesystem API should suffice. Any other features not regarding web in general should be implemented through NPAPI. I think you might have a chance with Flash but I'm not sure.

Comment: NPAPI is no longer an option. Chrome removed support for it in September 2015. Source: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213033?hl=en